# AngularJS REST service on PhoneGap

Tags: angularjs, rest, cordova

I'm trying to call my web page to get data in phonegap. I've put it on external server (webpage) and when I'm trying this on localhost everything works, but when I emulate it - it doesn't.

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','ngResource','offiservServices']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.

    when('/',{
        controller : 'MainCtrl',
        templateUrl : 'views/login.html'
    });
}]);

var myAppServices = angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource']);

myAppServices.factory('User', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://[my-webPage]/backend.php', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', isArray:false}
    });
  }]);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','User',function($scope,User) {

    $scope.user = User.query();
}]);
```

**login.html**

```
Username: {{ user.user }}
<br>
Password: {{ user.pass }}
```

my webpage is returning an array ('user'=>'user','pass'=>'test') and as I said on localhost everything works fine ( I've added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` on backend.php ).

So on localhost I get `Username: user Password: test` but on PhoneGap I get `Username:   Password:`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a debugger to have control about what's happening in your app.

There are many different methods to debug your app, some examples:

- Weinre: https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/
- Google developer tools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation

Comment: I have something like that in my config.xml: " <access origin=".*"/>" so I guess it should work?

Comment: I think configuration works, and did you try to debug and see what are you sending?

Comment: you mean what i'm sending from page? When I alerted whole "data" in PhoneGap I got an object, so I guess some data is being sent. I don't know what data but I surely know that I'm not getting the same as on localhost..

Comment: i used to use for debugging weinre... it allows you to see all for ajax calls as in firebug. its very simple to use, just adding a line from this website in your code. http://debug.phonegap.com/

Comment: well.. I added a line and don't really know what's next?:P on localhost I see the requests are being sent but..how can I debug with that?

Comment: You have to do 4 steps: 1º) you enter in debug.phonegap.com and change the input with a custom string like for example: "mypersonaltest". 2º) You will see the script changed, so add the new line in your code like "<script src="http://debug.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#mypersonaltest"></script>". 3º) go to the url created http://debug.phonegap.com/client/#mypersonaltest 4º) run your app... after this steps, the page should refresh with your application and you can see your network transfers :)

Comment: Well two things: I think You should edit Your answer and add this last comment You posted and second: um..I'm getting empty response ( I get only "[]" - here is the link http://debug.phonegap.com/ws/client/1546084606 ).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but this tool is very effective to "console" an app in cordova/phonegap (and everything else!)

You can also use http://jsconsole.com/

Execute the following command:

```
:listen
```

and you will get a line something like:

```
<script src="http://jsconsole.com/remote.js?DCDB11CC-66D8-47F7-8DF1-FA69B2D49E17"></script>
```

Therefore, you put that line in your code and every output to the console will be inmediatelly output to your jsconsole page!